# How to change plaseholder when i used input tag as submit button

Tags: php, html

I want button name as `Next page` instead of `value` how can i do?

```
<input type="submit" name="url" value="value" placeholder="Next page">
```

I tried above code using placeholder attribute but it doesn't work. furthermore i don't want to use button.

Comment: You simply _can not_ specifiy a different display text, and submission value, with `<input type="submit">`. The `value` _is_ what is getting displayed as the button text. _“furthermore i don't want to use button”_ - but that _would be_ the appropriate element for what you want. So without any proper explanation, _why_ you would not or could not use it … this question is rather pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML `<button>` Tag :

```
<button type="button">Next Page</button>
```

Comment: I can't do that

Comment: You can't use placeholder if your input field type is submit

Comment: I just want button name as Next Page instead of value